# scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double (Spark)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
root
 |-- midx: double (nullable = true)
 |-- future: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- _2: long (nullable = false)
```

Using this code I am trying to transfer it into something like this:

```
val T = withFfutures.where($"midx" === 47.0).select("midx","future").collect().map((row: Row) =>
      Row {
        row.getAs[Seq[Row]]("future").map { case Row(e: Long, f: Long) =>
          (row.getAs[Double]("midx"), e, f)
        }
      }
    ).toList

root
 |-- id: double (nullable = true)
 |-- event: long (nullable = true)
 |-- future: long (nullable = true)
```

So the plan is to transfer the array of (event, future) into a dataframe that has those two fields as a column. I am trying to transfer T into a DataFrame like this:

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("id", DoubleType, nullable = true)
  , StructField("event", LongType, nullable = true)
  , StructField("future", LongType, nullable = true)
))

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(context.parallelize(T), schema)
```

But when I a, trying to look into the `df` I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

Comment: I'm drawing a blank here. You reference `midx` and then you use `id` without ever defining it.

Comment: Isn't (row.getAs[Double]("midx") the way to say that this double is  'id'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I found what was the problem: First and foremost that Array of structs in the column should be casted to Row. So the final code to build the final data frame should look like this:

```
val T = withFfutures.select("midx","future").collect().flatMap( (row: Row) =>
    row.getAs[Seq[Row]]("future").map { case Row(e: Long, f: Long) =>
      (row.getAs[Double]("midx") , e, f)
    }.toList
).toList

val all = context.parallelize(T).toDF("id","event","future")
```

Comment: The schema is also not necessary.